# Wireless mic problem: Amplitude sounds like it is "jittering" up and down by a few db

Tags: audio-recording, microphone, noise, wireless

We are having a strange problem with our set of Audio Technica 1800 series wireless lavs.

It seems as though the amplitude of the sound is jittering up and down by a few db. It throws the dynamic of the vocal and makes it difficult to listen to. It sounds like some awful auto-gain.

Incidentally, sometimes there is white noise that comes in and out with the vocal - kind of like room tone when you have an expander on too hard.

The buildings we are in do tend to have a lot of wireless devices transmitting and receiving but we've tried changing frequencies a few times to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this sort of thing happen on devices that don't have enough built in protection from interference. I ended up having to ditch my old kit as it just didn't cope any more.

You could have a look at folks like [Skytronic](http://www.chamberlainmusic.com/ProductDetail.asp?ProductID=SK171360) - disclaimer: I didn't end up buying this one, although it did appear to meet my interference requirements. I ended up just staying wired for now.